# MacOS spinning beach ball with application freeze

Tags: macos, freeze

I have an Openframeworks install that I thoroughly tested and relaunch on a daily basis. Every few days I encounter the wonderful OSX 'spinning beach ball' and the entire application is frozen, and I am not even able to log in remotely.

There are obviously a ton of possibly causes, but can anyone suggest some troubleshooting steps?
Is it possible this is a memory leak issue?

Answer (score 0):

To see what a process is doing when something goes wrong, use `sample(1)`.

To see what the whole system is doing (including kernel threads that might be the culprits), use `spindump(8)`.

Comment: thanks!. Unfortunately when the machine is in this state, everything is frozen, my only option is a manual reboot(hitting the power button)

Comment: @eco_bach How were you trying to log in remotely? If you were using VNC/screen sharing, try SSH instead. Consider opening up an SSH session into this box before the problem happens, and keeping it open until the problem occurs.